# Python upgrade to 3.5 from 2.7 for a different project using virtualenv in windows 10

Tags: python, django

I am a new to Python/Django

I am using python 2.7.12 in windows 10 platform.

Django version is for another project is 1.10.1

I have installed virtualenvwrapper.

Now I am in the process to setup a dev platform for a project where python 3.5 is required. I have another project where I am using py 2.7

I would like to update python version(not globally) but only for my current project.

Any help(steps or a link) is highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)

Comment: Thanks I already have seen that thread. It's a different OS(debian) though.

Comment: As fat as I know the commands of `virtualenv` are the same, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have created and activated the new env. In that new env I get the python version as 2.7.12. Now I need to upgrade the py version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple virtual environments .
Just create one more virtual environment and activate it then install Python 3.5 and required Django .

You can download Anaconda, after the installation from cmd type this:

```
conda create --name environmentname python=3.5
```

after installation just type:

```
activate environmentname
```

then just type :

```
pip install django
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have created a virtualenv and activated it. Now do I need to create a requirments.txt file and write python 3.5 manually and then run the file?

Comment: while installing python mention version name, you can check version just by typing python in the console.

Comment: Do I need to delete the newly created envname and then use the above command -- conda create --name environmentname python=3.5

Comment: you can use either , If you install anaconda then only conda will work

Comment: Ok I am installing it now.

Comment: I am able to using 3.5 under new environment using conda. So when I go back to windows default prompt and activate the new env it still showing 2.7.1 where as in conda prompt it shows 3.5

Comment: yes because both are using different environments , just use environment created by conda for development , and kindly raise the answer so others can also follow if needed.

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have one more question. In normal python I do >>python manage.py runserver and then I can hit the url in browser. How can I do the same using conda?

Comment: every commands are same , only thing is u have to start the virtual environment

Comment: Yes that was sorted out. Now a new issue with python 34. I can't install mysql-python module.